# Adding a second field to QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

I am using PyQGIS within my work and I currently have a script that uses QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer to symbolise my data. Previously, I have used a script that symbolises my data using CategorizedSymbolRenderer (see script below). However, this prints out too many values on my exported map, so I have decided to use Graduated instead, so that I can use min/max values to classify my data.

```
default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp('Spectral')  # Spectral color ramp
color_ramp.invert()

layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('Intensity')[0]

exp_string = '\'Intensity: \' || "Intensity" || \'\nAffected Population: \' || sum("LAC_Popu_1", "Intensity")'
unique_values = []
exp = QgsExpression(exp_string)
#print(exp.isValid())
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalScope())
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()))
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.atlasScope(None))
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer))
exp.prepare(context)
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    context.setFeature(feat)
    val = exp.evaluate(context)
    if val not in unique_values:
        unique_values.append(val)
# print(unique_values)

categories = []
for value in sorted(unique_values):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    category = QgsRendererCategory(value, symbol, str(value))
    categories.append(category)
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(exp_string, categories)
renderer.updateColorRamp(color_ramp)
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.setOpacity(0.55)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

My script that I have created so far retrieves intensity data from a field called 'Intensity' within my vlayer and uses Graduated Symbology to say if the intensity is between 1.0 - 1.99 for example, then a blue colour is given. This script runs perfectly fine to produce graduated intensity values with corresponding colour. However, I am struggling to get the 'Affected Population' factor within my label, like previously shown, where a value is underneath each intensity. The affected population field will have no involvement as to how the graduated symbology is laid out, it is just extra information for each intensity. This script is as follows:

```
Intensity_rules = (
    ('MMI Intensity 1.0 - 1.99', 0.0, 1.99, '#2b83ba'),
    ('MMI Intensity 2.0 - 2.99', 2.0, 2.99, '#71b4ae'),
    ('MMI Intensity 3.0 - 3.99', 3.0, 3.99, '#abdda4'),
    ('MMI Intensity 4.0 - 4.99', 4.0, 4.99, '#d4eeb1'),
    ('MMI Intensity 5.0 - 5.99', 5.0, 5.99, '#ffffbf'),
    ('MMI Intensity 6.0 - 6.99', 6.0, 6.99, '#fed58e'),
    ('MMI Intensity 7.0 - 7.99', 7.0, 7.99, '#fdae61'),
    ('MMI Intensity 8.0 - 8.99', 8.0, 8.99, '#ee7144'),
    ('MMI Intensity 9.0 - 9.99', 9.0, 9.99, '#d7191c'),
    ('MMI Intensity 10.0 - 10.99', 10.0, 10.99, '#d7191c'),
)

# create a category for each item in intensity
ranges = []
for label, lower, upper, color in Intensity_rules:
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor(color))
    rng = QgsRendererRange(lower, upper, symbol, label)
    ranges.append(rng)

#create the renderer and assign it to layer
expression = '"Intensity" ' #field name '\'Intensity: \' || "Intensity" || \'\nAffected Population: \' || sum("LAC_Popu_1", "Intensity")'
renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(expression, ranges)
vlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
vlayer.setOpacity(0.70)
vlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

I run zonal statistics on the intensity shapefile layer, along with a population raster, to produce an affected population column called "LAC_Popu_1". Is there a way I can add this column of produced statistics underneath each line of intensity like in this first script/photo where I used Categorized symbology e.g.
MMI Intensity 1.0 - 1.99: 'Blue colour'
Affected Population: 545432

Comment: Where does 545432 value come from?

Comment: Hi Kadir, I have just used '545432' as an example of the affected population. It could be any number when calculated. This affected population is under the field column called "LAC_Popu_1". Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the sum of the affected population for every class ?
Like :
MMI Intensity 1.0 - 1.99: 'Blue colour' Affected Population: 545432
MMI Intensity 2.0 - 2.99: 'Light Blue colour' Affected Population: 70000
etc...
Or do you want the affected for every circle even if it's the same class ? If you have n circle you have n value :
MMI Intensity 1.0 - 1.99: 'Blue colour' Affected Population: 270000 ,275432
MMI Intensity 2.0 - 2.99: 'Light Blue colour' Affected Population: 30000,20000,10000,10000

Comment: Hi @JULESG , I would like the sum of the affected population for every class, if that is okay! So for just MMI Intensity 1.0 - 1.99, there is only one affected population value with it. And for 2.0 - 2.99, only one affected population value with it too. Hope this makes sense! (the first option you gave in your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain something like this :

[image: Result]

You can do a loop in your layer to sum the affected population by class :

```
minimum = 1
maximum = 10.99
n = 1
result = []
while n < maximum :
    total = 0
    select_features = QgsExpression( "{intensity_field} >= '{lower}' and {intensity_field} < '{upper}'".format(intensity_field = "Intensity", lower = n, upper = n+1))
    for f in vlayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest( select_features )):
        attrs = f.attributes()
        value = attrs[vlayer.fields().indexFromName("LAC_Popu_1")]
        total = total + value
    result.append(total)
    n = n + 1
```

You now have a list, `result`,  with every sum for every class with `index(0)` is the first class and `index(-1)` the last.

You can modify your rules to add the sum to your label :

```
    Intensity_rules = (
    ('MMI Intensity 1.0 - 1.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[0]), 0.0, 1.99, '#2b83ba'),
    ('MMI Intensity 2.0 - 2.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[1]), 2.0, 2.99, '#71b4ae'),
    ('MMI Intensity 3.0 - 3.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[2]), 3.0, 3.99, '#abdda4'),
    ('MMI Intensity 4.0 - 4.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[3]), 4.0, 4.99, '#d4eeb1'),
    ('MMI Intensity 5.0 - 5.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[4]), 5.0, 5.99, '#ffffbf'),
    ('MMI Intensity 6.0 - 6.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[5]), 6.0, 6.99, '#fed58e'),
    ('MMI Intensity 7.0 - 7.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[6]), 7.0, 7.99, '#fdae61'),
    ('MMI Intensity 8.0 - 8.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[7]), 8.0, 8.99, '#ee7144'),
    ('MMI Intensity 9.0 - 9.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[8]), 9.0, 9.99, '#d7191c'),
    ('MMI Intensity 10.0 - 10.99' + '\n Affected Population : ' + str(result[9]), 10.0, 10.99, '#d7191c'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That is exactly what I wanted :)